# Create true color image from Sentinel-1 data

Tags: qgis-processing, satellite

Is it possible to create or extract a true color (RGB) image from Sentinal-1 satellite data?

Like with Landsat8 data described in this article [https://scientiaplusconscientia.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/working-with-landsat-8-a-tutorial-2-creating-simple-composites/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528121610/https://scientiaplusconscientia.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/working-with-landsat-8-a-tutorial-2-creating-simple-composites/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is physically impossible due to Sentinel-1 using a **SAR (Synthetic Aperture Radar)** sensor instead of an **optical** sensor.

You can create *false color RGB* images from SAR data but no true color RGB.

If you are looking for optical remote sensing imagery, besides Landsat, the recently launched [**Sentinel-2**](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2) is expected to deliver it's first images soon.

Comment: Can you explain the steps to creating the false colour in QGIS?

Comment: @Johanna You can assign different bands to each color. One option would be: R: VV polarization, G: VH polarization, B: ratio of both polarizations. You can do this in QGIS by right clicking on a layer Properties -> Style -> Multiband Color. There you can select which band should be displayed in which color.

Comment: In Layer Properties, if I try to use Multiband Color, I still only have grey as an option. If I open the data with the SNAP tools, I can see that I have two bands, but I can't see them in QGIS.

Comment: S1 data is distributed as 1 band per image file. You'll need to create a multiband first.